# JPA HQL query with where condition on FK colums

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I have 2 entities with a onetomany relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Project {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="project",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private java.util.List<RmtService> services = new ArrayList<RmtService>();

}
```

and:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Service implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
private Project project;

    // . . .
 }
```

There is a way to do a JPA query that generates a SQL query like:

```
select * from service where project_id=?
```

??

All the queries that I have tried generate always a join on the Project table.

I tried:

```
select s from Service s left join fetch s.project pp where pp.id = :id
```

that generates

```
select rmtservice0_.id as id1_1_0_, project1_.id as id1_0_1_, 
rmtservice0_.project_id as project3_1_0_, rmtservice0_.serviceType 
as serviceT2_1_0_, project1_.name as name2_0_1_, project1_.surname
as surname3_0_1_ from RmtService rmtservice0_ 
left outer join Project project1_ on rmtservice0_.project_id=project1_.id 
where   project1_.id=?
```

and

```
select s from RmtService s where s.project.id = :id
```

that generates 2 queries:

```
select rmtservice0_.id as id1_1_, rmtservice0_.project_id as project3_1_, 
rmtservice0_.serviceType as serviceT2_1_ from RmtService rmtservice0_ where 
rmtservice0_.project_id=?

select project0_.id as id1_0_0_, project0_.name as name2_0_0_, project0_.surname
as surname3_0_0_ from Project project0_ where project0_.id=?
```

thanks a lot

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: changed inline in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s FROM Service s
WHERE s.project = :project
```

Comment: thanks a lot! actually even this version fired 2 queries because I did not force the @ManyToOne to be lazy, when I changed it to lazy it worked fine.

Comment: I did think that may be the case. Glad that I could help.